# How to display the random images in the header using dynamic header plugin?

Tags: wordpress

I have my wordpress site and I have installed the dynamic header plugin.
I have 5 images in the "header images" directory.

I want to display 3 of that 5 images randomly on a specific page? How will I do this?

I select random media header in my page but it displays all of the 5 images randomly.

What should I do with this to display only that 3 images randomly on my page?

Comment: You may have more luck with this question on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the plugin can do this by default, however you can try and add the following function to your `custom-header.php`:

```
function dh_get_random_media_item_filebased($files = array()) {
    global $dhnd_image_dir;
    //Open the media directory and add all of the images to an array.
    if ($media_dir = opendir($dhnd_image_dir)) {
        while ($m_file = readdir($media_dir)) {
            if ($m_file != '.' && $m_file != '..' && in_array($m_file, $file)) {
                $media_array[] = $m_file;
            }
        }
    }
    return $media_array[rand(0, count($media_array) - 1)];
}
```

Then when you call `dh_get_random_media_item_filebased()` you would specify the names of the files you would like it to randomize:

```
$names = array('header1.jpg', 'header2.jpg', 'header3.jpg');
dh_get_random_media_item_filebased($names);
```

In your themes `page.php` file you could then do something like this:

```
global $post; //wordpress post global object
//
if ($post->post_type == 'page'){
   $names = array();
   switch ($post->post_name) {
     case 'sample-page':
         $names = array('image-1.jpg', 'image-2.jpg', 'image-3.jpg');
        break;
     case 'sample-page-2':
         $names = array('image-4.jpg', 'image-5.jpg');
        break;
     default:
         $names = array('image-1.jpg',
                        'image-2.jpg',
                        'image-3.jpg',
                        'image-4.jpg',
                        'image-5.jpg',
         );
        break;     
   }
   $images = dh_get_random_media_item_filebased($names);
}
```

Of course you could change the `$post->post_name` in the switch statement to check for and `ID` or similar i.e `$post->ID`.

Comment: But I want to display the image 1 on one page, image 2 on other page and then randomly display the remaining three images on another page.

Comment: Now what code should I use? As you give me three code snippets. The firs code I will place in the custom-header.php, the second in my theme's header.php and the third in page.php?